# Ubuntu Does Not See Any Partition in My Hard Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-10

I tried to install Ubuntu along with Windows 10. I followed step by step of this tutorial on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNeJvujdB-0.

1. I copied a boot-able Ubuntu to an USB Drive
2. On "Installation Type" window: "This computer currently has no detected operating systems. What would you like to do?"
3. I still kept trying to follow the tutorial, then chose "Something else"
   [image]
   Up until this point, I am stuck because Ubuntu seem does not recognize any partition in my hard drive.

Could anybody help me pointing out the problem and how can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Porbably you have an unsupported setting for drives at UEFI. First of all, install AHCI drivers in Windows 10. Then reboot to UEFI settings and change the drive's mode from RAID to AHCI.

Comment: Please run the *Try Ubuntu without installing* option in the Ubuntu live DVD/USB and start the GParted application. Then take a screenshot of the partitions that are shown in GParted, upload the screenshot to any image sharing website and provide a link to it.